# MAUI - Calculate collection view grid columns using available width

Tags: c#, xaml, maui, maui-windows

I, i am exploring .NET MAUI, and trying to sample some things, and one thing i came across was, how can i calculate a collection view grid column number, to fit the available space.

I managed to get it working on some way, but only discovered how to get de device screen width, but my main goal is to use the app on desktop too, and on desktop not always going to be used on full screen, so the calculation does not work very well.

So far i got this, using a binding to the calculation on the view model using the device screen width, to the GridItemsLayout Span:

XAML:

```
<StackLayout>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}"
                        x:Name="clvMenuItems">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout 
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    Span="{Binding NumHorizontalViewMenuItems}"
                    VerticalItemSpacing="4"
                    HorizontalItemSpacing="4" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, *" BackgroundColor="Orange">
                        <ImageButton Grid.Row="0"
                           HorizontalOptions="Start"
                           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="25,12,39,39"
                           Margin="16,16,0,8"
                            MaximumHeightRequest="50"
                           Source="{Binding Icon}"/>

                        <Label VerticalOptions="Start"
                           HorizontalOptions="End"
                           IsVisible="{Binding ShowBadge}"
                           WidthRequest="38"
                           Margin="16"
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           FontSize="16"
                           Text="NEW"
                           TextColor="{DynamicResource BadgeThemeColor}"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="1"
                           VerticalTextAlignment="End"
                           Margin="16,0,10,16"
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                           Text="{Binding Name}"
                           FontSize="16"
                           FontFamily="Roboto"
                           MaxLines="2"
                           LineHeight="1"
                           LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                           TextColor="{DynamicResource TextThemeColor}"
                           BackgroundColor="Transparent" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
```

ViewModel:

```
        public int NumHorizontalViewMenuItems => CalcHorizontalViewMenuItems();

        static int MenuItemMaxWidth = 120;

        private int CalcHorizontalViewMenuItems()
        {
            return (int)Math.Floor(DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Width / MenuItemMaxWidth);
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? There may be a different way if you elaborate on your goal. You may want to try out [FlexLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/flexlayout)

Comment: I am trying to achieve some kind of simple dynamic page of buttons, that fill out the space available accordingly the app size, on mobile and desktop. Somewhat like a tyle menu, but on bigger screens it can fit more horizontally for example, and smaller screens less, and grows vertically. I was trying to use the collectionview because it supports data templating and selection change, and flexlayout, of what i know, does not supports something like that.

Comment: You can use a [BindableLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/bindablelayout) in conjunction with a FlexLayout. The BindableLayout provides the possibility for templates. None of the layout views support selection, only ListView and CollectionView have this feature, AFAIK.

Comment: Many thanks, didn´t know about the bindablelayout, i tried it, and with flexlayout i achieved what i was looking for. Thanks again.

Comment: You could add your solution as an answer below  That way, future readers with a similar problem can benefit from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Has @ewerspej suggested, i used FlexLayout with a BindableLayout instead of CollectionView, because its design is more equal to what i was trying to reach, some kind of a tyle menu, that fits more on bigger screens or less on smaller screens.

I leave here a sample of what i've done:

```
<ScrollView VerticalOptions="Start">
    <FlexLayout VerticalOptions="Start"
                HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                Direction="Row"
                Wrap="Wrap"
                AlignContent="Start"
                AlignItems="Start"
                JustifyContent="Start"
                Margin="5"
                Padding="0"
                BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, *" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Margin="2">
                    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer 
                            Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:MainViewModel}}, Path=OpenMenuCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>

                    <Image Grid.Row="0"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="25,12,39,39"
                       Margin="5"
                       MaximumHeightRequest="50"
                       MaximumWidthRequest="50"
                       Source="{Binding Icon}"/>

                    <Label VerticalOptions="Start"
                       HorizontalOptions="End"
                       IsVisible="{Binding ShowBadge}"
                       WidthRequest="38"
                       Margin="5"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                       FontSize="14"
                       Text="NEW"
                       TextColor="{DynamicResource BadgeThemeColor}"/>
                    
                    <Label Grid.Row="1"
                       VerticalTextAlignment="End"
                       Margin="5,0,5,5"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                       Text="{Binding Name}"
                       FontSize="16"
                       FontFamily="Roboto"
                       WidthRequest="90"
                       MaximumWidthRequest="90"
                       MaxLines="3"
                       LineHeight="1"
                       LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                       TextColor="{DynamicResource TextThemeColor}"
                       BackgroundColor="Transparent" />

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    </FlexLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Thanks for the help.